# How to check if the database exists in PCL xamarin mvvmcross

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

### How to check if the database exists

***I am creating a Sqlite database Android but written code in core PCL***

```
       SQLiteConnection dbConn;

        #region Constructor
        public CreateTableService()
        {
            dbConn = new SQLiteConnection(CommonCodes.getSqliteAndroidPath());

            //Creating Tables
            CreateTables();
        }
        #endregion
```

---

```
public static string getSqliteAndroidPath()
        {
            var filepath = Mvx.Resolve<IMvxFileStore>();
            return filepath.NativePath(Constants.DbStella);
        }
```

Comment: Is `Mvx.Resolve<IMvxFileStore>().TryReadBinaryFile(...)` not acceptable? or do you explicitly need to check the path and not the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the File plugin includes an [Exists(string path)](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/tree/develop/MvvmCross-Plugins/File#file) method you can use to see if the db file already exists.